# Reading from a UDP port in C/C++ via a Win32 application

Tags: c++, c, winapi, sockets, udp

I am completely and utterly new to socket programming so please bear with the stupidity of my question

I would love if someone could show/send/help me with the absolute minimum needed to read from a UDP port via a win32 application written in C/C++.

I want to be able to specify the port to read from (Hardcoded) and then just take data straight from there.

I would be exceptionally grateful forany help

Thankyou

Comment: @hexa http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: `socket`, `bind`, `recvfrom`...

Comment: @cnicutar. I'm sorry. I'll be emailing james the code.

Comment: There's sample client and server code for WIn32 UDP here. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/udptime.aspx

Comment: @cnicutar: The ban on lmgtfy specifically concerns the fact that some people find it demeaning.  Don't assume that it means "Try google" or "Have you already searched google?" aren't appropriate answers to certain questions.

Comment: @Ben Voigt It was simply a suggestion not to downvote him right away :)

Comment: @hexa, you might also find this discussion interesting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96639/130940

Comment: @MarkRansom interesting indeed

Answer (score 6):

[The MSDN documentation for `recvfrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740120.aspx) contains a complete example.

Comment: @hexa: Note that I'm sending the same message "You really should read the docs for this information" by providing a link and no code.  But in a way that no one will complain about (at least until MSDN rearranges their links, at which point a reader will actually have to find the recvfrom page themselves, which isn't exactly a bad thing either)

Comment: that's a canonical link I think.  The version-specific ones have the compiler revision in them.

Comment: @Steve: I took out the version-specific part, but that's no guarantee that the 740120 page id will be meaningful six months from now.  MSDN has a history of link-breaking reorganization.

Comment: agreed - I think the docs that are specific to a given compiler or framework version are more reliable, Winsock is outside that scope